# MySQL has gone away: Connection_errors_peer_address with high numbers

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

We have MySQL 5.7 master - slaves replications and on the slave servers side, it hapens from time to time that our application monitoring tools (Tideways and PHP7.0) are reporting

> MySQL has gone away.

Checking the MYSQL side:

```
show global status like '%Connection%';

+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Connection_errors_accept          | 0        |
| Connection_errors_internal        | 0        |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0        |
| Connection_errors_peer_address    | 323      |
| Connection_errors_select          | 0        |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap         | 0        |
| Connections                       | 55210496 |
| Max_used_connections              | 387      |
| Slave_connections                 | 0        |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

The `Connection_errors_peer_address` shows 323. How to further investigate on what is causing this issue on both sides:

> MySQL has gone away

and

> Connection_errors_peer_address

EDIT:

Master Server

```
net_retry_count = 10 
net_read_timeout = 120 
net_write_timeout = 120 
skip_networking = OFF
Aborted_clients = 151650
```

Slave Server 1

```
net_retry_count = 10
net_read_timeout = 30 
net_write_timeout = 60 
skip_networking = OFF
Aborted_clients = 3
```

Slave Server 2

```
net_retry_count = 10
net_read_timeout = 30 
net_write_timeout = 60 
skip_networking = OFF
Aborted_clients = 3
```

Comment: what's the value of `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` in my.cnf on the master node?

Comment: This may occur due to Server timed out. To fix this please check that wait_timeout mysql variable in configuration file is sufficient or not.

Comment: @Alexey: `wait_timeout = 600` and `max_allowed_packet = 100M`

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL 5.7, when a new TCP/IP connection reaches the server, the server performs several checks, implemented in `sql/sql_connect.cc` in function `check_connection()`

One of these checks is to get the IP address of the client side connection, as in:

```
static int check_connection(THD *thd)
{
...
  if (!thd->m_main_security_ctx.host().length)     // If TCP/IP connection
  {
...
    peer_rc= vio_peer_addr(net->vio, ip, &thd->peer_port, NI_MAXHOST);
    if (peer_rc)
    {
      /*
        Since we can not even get the peer IP address,
        there is nothing to show in the host_cache,
        so increment the global status variable for peer address errors.
      */
      connection_errors_peer_addr++;
      my_error(ER_BAD_HOST_ERROR, MYF(0));
      return 1;
    }
...
}
```

Upon failure, the status variable `connection_errors_peer_addr` is incremented, and the connection is rejected.

`vio_peer_addr()` is implemented in `vio/viosocket.c` (code simplified to show only the important calls)

```
my_bool vio_peer_addr(Vio *vio, char *ip_buffer, uint16 *port,
                      size_t ip_buffer_size)
{
  if (vio->localhost)
  {
...
  }
  else
  {
    /* Get sockaddr by socked fd. */

    err_code= mysql_socket_getpeername(vio->mysql_socket, addr, &addr_length);

    if (err_code)
    {
      DBUG_PRINT("exit", ("getpeername() gave error: %d", socket_errno));
      DBUG_RETURN(TRUE);
    }

    /* Normalize IP address. */

    vio_get_normalized_ip(addr, addr_length,
                          (struct sockaddr *) &vio->remote, &vio->addrLen);

    /* Get IP address & port number. */

    err_code= vio_getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &vio->remote,
                              ip_buffer, ip_buffer_size,
                              port_buffer, NI_MAXSERV,
                              NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);

    if (err_code)
    {
      DBUG_PRINT("exit", ("getnameinfo() gave error: %s",
                          gai_strerror(err_code)));
      DBUG_RETURN(TRUE);
    }
...
  }
...
}
```

In short, the only failure path in `vio_peer_addr()` happens when a call to `mysql_socket_getpeername()` or `vio_getnameinfo()` fails.

mysql_socket_getpeername() is just a wrapper on top of getpeername().

The `man 2 getpeername` manual lists the following possible errors:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    getpeername - get name of connected peer socket
> ```
>
> ERRORS
>
> ```
>    EBADF  The argument sockfd is not a valid descriptor.
>
>    EFAULT The addr argument points to memory not in a valid part of the process address space.
>
>    EINVAL addrlen is invalid (e.g., is negative).
>
>    ENOBUFS
>           Insufficient resources were available in the system to perform the operation.
>
>    ENOTCONN
>           The socket is not connected.
>
>    ENOTSOCK
>           The argument sockfd is a file, not a socket.
> ```

Of these errors, only `ENOBUFS` is plausible.

As for `vio_getnameinfo()`, it is just a wrapper on getnameinfo(), which also according to the man page `man 3 getnameinfo` can fail for the following reasons:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    getnameinfo - address-to-name translation in protocol-independent manner
> ```
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    EAI_AGAIN
>           The name could not be resolved at this time.  Try again later.
>
>    EAI_BADFLAGS
>           The flags argument has an invalid value.
>
>    EAI_FAIL
>           A nonrecoverable error occurred.
>
>    EAI_FAMILY
>           The address family was not recognized, or the address length was invalid for the specified family.
>
>    EAI_MEMORY
>           Out of memory.
>
>    EAI_NONAME
>           The name does not resolve for the supplied arguments.  NI_NAMEREQD is set and the host's name cannot be located, or neither
> ```
>
> hostname  nor  service  name
>                 were requested.
>
> ```
>    EAI_OVERFLOW
>           The buffer pointed to by host or serv was too small.
>
>    EAI_SYSTEM
>           A system error occurred.  The error code can be found in errno.
>
>    The gai_strerror(3) function translates these error codes to a human readable string, suitable for error reporting.
> ```

Here many failures can happen, basically due to heavy load or the network.

To understand the process behind this code, what the MySQL server is essentially doing is a [Reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), to:

- find the hostname of the client
- find the IP address corresponding to this hostname
  to later convert this IP address to a hostname again (see the call to ip_to_hostname() that follows).

Overall, failures accounted with `Connection_errors_peer_address` can be due to system load (causing transient failures like out of memory, etc) or due to network issues affecting DNS.

Disclosure: I happen to be the person who implemented this `Connection_errors_peer_address` status variable in MySQL, as part of an effort to have better visibility / observability in this area of the code.

[Edit] To follow up with more details and/or guidelines:

- When `Connection_errors_peer_address` is incremented, the root cause is not printed in logs. That is unfortunate for troubleshooting, but also avoid flooding logs causing even more damage, there is a tradeoff here. Keep in mind that anything that happen *before* logging in is very sensitive ...
- If the server really goes out of memory, it is very likely that many other things will break, and that the server will go down very quickly. By monitoring the total memory usage of `mysqld`, and monitoring the `uptime`, it should be fairly easy to determine if the failure "only" caused connections to be closed with the server staying up, or if the server itself failed catastrophically.
- Assuming the server stays up on failure, the more likely culprit is the second call then, to `getnameinfo`.
- Using `skip-name-resolve` will have no effect, as this check happens later (see `specialflag & SPECIAL_NO_RESOLVE` in the code in `check_connection()`)
- When `Connection_errors_peer_address` fails, note that the server cleanly returns the error `ER_BAD_HOST_ERROR` to the client, and then closes the socket. This is different from just closing abruptly a socket (like in a crash) : the former should be reported by the client as `"Can't get hostname for your address"`, while the later is reported as `"MySQL has gone away"`.
- Whether the client connector actually treat `ER_BAD_HOST_ERROR` and a socket closed differently is another story

Given that this failure overall seems related to DNS lookups, I would check the following items:

- See how many rows are in the `performance_schema.host_cache` table.
- Compare this with the size of the host cache, see the `host_cache_size` system variable.
- If the host cache appear full, consider increasing its size: this will reduce the number of DNS calls overall, relieving pressure on DNS, in hope (admittedly, this is just a shot in the dark) that DNS transient failures will disappear.
- 323 out of 55 million connections indeed seems transient. Assuming the monitoring client sometime do get connected properly, inspect the row in table host_cache for this client: it may contains *other* failures reported.

Table `performance_schema.host_cache` documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache-table.html

Further readings:

http://marcalff.blogspot.com/2012/04/performance-schema-nailing-host-cache.html

[Edit 2] Based on the new data available:

The `Aborted_clients` status variable shows some connections forcefully closed by the server. This typically happens when a session is idle for a very long time.

A typical scenario for this to happen is:

1. A client opens a connection, and sends some queries
2. Then the client does nothing for an extended amount of time (greater than the net_read_timeout)
3. Due to lack of traffic, the server closes the session, and increments Aborted_connects
4. The client then sends another query, sees a closed connection, and reports "MySQL has gone away"

Note that a client application forgetting to cleanly close sessions will execute 1-3, this could be the case for Aborted_clients on the master. Some cleanup here to fix clients applications using the master would help to decrease resource consumption, as leaving 151650 sessions open to die on timeout has a cost.

A client application executing 1-4 can cause Aborted_clients on the server *and* MySQL has gone away on the client. The client application reporting "MySQL has gone away" is most likely the culprit here.

If a monitoring application, say, checks the server every N seconds, then make sure the timeouts (here 30 and 60 sec) are significantly greater that N, or the server will kill the monitoring session.

Comment: Is `skip-name-resolve` relevant?  If so, is it a 'solution'?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description Marc. The `Connection_errors_peer_address` was a potential source of information I was trying to investigate on while getting the MySQL has gone away message on the PHP side. You mentioned that the `Connection_errors_peer_address` can be due to system load or network issues affecting DNS. How to find out what really happened. Is ther something storred in the MySQL logs when the `Connection_errors_peer_address` gets incremented so that I can explore and find out what really happens.

Comment: @RickJames, You mean starting MySQL with `skip-name-resolve` so that the function `check_connection` is not triggered, then eliminate this source of errors?

Comment: @Miloš - I don't know for sure; I am guessing.  (Hence, I did not present it as an 'Answer'.

Comment: Roger that, thanks. I was more expecting to get an answer to that comment from @MarcAlff.

Comment: @RickJames, Milos - Sorry for the delay. See updated answer.

Comment: @MarcAlff, thank you once again. `host_cache_size` = 703 but there are no entries in the `performance_schema.host_cache table`

Comment: @Milos - Thanks for the update. The host_cache table can appear empty when the performance schema is disabled. This hinders observability, but is not a root cause here.

Comment: @MarcAlff, any idea on what else to investigate in order to find out what could be the cause of the MySQL has gone away?

Comment: @milos - "MySQL has gone away" is a socket closed seen from the client side. Check for Aborted_clients, net_retry_count, net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout. ... this all points to the network. Make sure there are no forgotten clean up scripts that KILL sessions. Check also for disconnect_on_expired_password.

Comment: @MarcAlff,thanks once again. I'm not at the highest level regarding MySQ. Checked those variables: `disconnect_on_expired_password = ON`
`net_retry_count = 10`
`net_read_timeout = 120`
`net_write_timeout = 120`
`skip_networking = OFF`

Comment: @Milos - I don't see anything odd here. The main question is whether the system still has peer address / disconnect errors _currently_, or only had some in the past. If there was a network glitch ages ago (I assume the server uptime is significant), finding _that_ is going to be very challenging ... What is the value of Aborted_clients ?

Comment: @MarcAlff, my appologies, I was pasting the Master MYSQL server variables, and there is a good chance the MySQL has gone away appeared on one of the two slave servers we have. I updated my question with the variables you asked for. Note that the MySQL has gone away happened 3 times in the last 2 weeks, last time 4 days ago.

Comment: @Milos - Just to make sure, when you say "MySQL has gone away", it is only an error seen from a client, but the server is still up, right ? This is visible in the server uptime.

Comment: @MarcAlff, that's right, the "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" is from the client side. The server is still up and running, uptime shows large values. The "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" just happened again on the client side.